# Multiple camera stream Acquistion for Video Analytics

Tags: opencv, video, artificial-intelligence, analytics

Hi I am working on a video analytics project which requires processing videos from multiple cameras simultaneously. Specifically I am concerned about architecture for stream acquisition:

**Current method:**

1. Pass ipcameras rtsp link to opencv "VideoCapture" and spawn this process for each cameras or use multithreading to acquire streams from different sources.

**Issues:**

1. Using multithreading I am getting variable frame rates which doesnt match the source settings for fps. And only get streams from some of the cameras not all even though I have started new threads for each camera.
2. open terminal and run one instance of code for each camera per terminal so n cameras n termninals. This gives good frame rate for 50% cameras and variable for the rest.

All these cameras are being accessed locally, which has bandwidth in gbps, 720p frames at 15-25 fps.

**My question is :**

1. Why do I get frame loss from rest of the cameras and how can I rectify the issue.
2. Better architecture for acquiring streams from different cameras , or any library or programming constructs suggested for this problem.